# Can someone please help me find a solution to my youtube embed problems?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, embed, videos, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to use a custom Parameter for youtube embed without using an iframe?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/any-way-to-use-a-custom-parameter-for-youtube-embed-without-using-an-iframe)

I have been trying to figure out the best way to do this, and I'm wondering if someone can tell me the best solution.  I want to be able to embed a youtube video into a wordpress post, take off the title (currently using "showinfo=0" on the end of the iframe embed), allow people who subscribe via RSS to either see the video in their rss reader, or have a link to direct people back to the post to watch the video, and also not have to worry about having problems with resizing the iframes when I change designs or themes at some point in time.

I've been trying to find a solution, but can't seem to find one. Everything I read seems to contradict something else. Does anyone out there know what the best way to do this? I do a video every single day, so it's really important to me that the videos work well. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any plugins yet? Give http://tubepress.org/ a try

Comment: I actually used one plug in a while back that I would put the youtube url into his little box on each post, and it would put some short code in my post. It didn't take the title off, but it did everything else very well. Another question I Have is, am I forced to use that plugin forever? Is there a way I can delete it, or switch plugins and not break all the videos I used that plug in for?

Comment: @ChipBennett Not really. This has to do with RSS reader as well. :)

Comment: The answer that was linked by @ChipBennet isn't about RSS or non-RSS. It's about ombed filtering.

Answer (score 0):

maybe isn't the answer to all your issues, but when i do use video i always use:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vipers-video-quicktags/

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between this plug in, and the one mentioned above? Also what do you use this plug in for that is different than what you get by just pasting the youtube url in wordpress?

Comment: @RickSmith The repo has a description page...

Comment: Yah, I saw that, but I couldn't tell what the differences are, or why you use it vs just letting wordpress embed. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why @chipbennett merged these two questions, they are actually dealing with different issues.

Comment: I didn't merge anything. I'm not a mod. :)

Comment: @ChipBennett Oh, I'm confused. It had your name next to the comment that said it was merged. I'm a bit confused. Now I have to go add another post...annoying.

Comment: @RickSmith those names indicate the users who *voted to close* the question. Also: I would recommend *revising your existing question*, rather than starting a new one. If the new question covers the same topic, it will also be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @ChipBennett It doesn't cover the same question, it's a totally different question. I'm assuming people just read your comment where you suggested it was a duplicate question and voted on it.