# Any way to use a custom Parameter for vimeo embed without using an iframe?

Tags: embed, oembed, parameter, vimeo

I am trying to get some oembed parameters attached to my Vimeo clips. I tried to get it going using the following two instructions:

- [Passing Parameters to a Vimeo link in a WordPress Custom Field](http://www.limecanvas.com/passing-parameters-to-a-video-link-in-a-wordpress-custom-field/) - LimeCanvas.com
- [Any way to use a custom parameter for YouTube embed without using an iframe](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/any-way-to-use-a-custom-parameter-for-youtube-embed-without-using-an-iframe) - WordPress.SE.com

Unfortunately what works for YouTube won't work for Vimeo, as the returning URL has no such string as `?feature=oembed` that I can make `str_replace` work on. It is just the video's id at the end of the URL, which is random. I can make it work if I enter the exact ID of the clip to make `str_replace` look for.

Any idea how to make the function look for numbers and attach the parameters? An example clip would be

```
http://vimeo.com/14956293
```

and the oEmbed should be

```
//player.vimeo.com/video/14956293?color=FFFFFF&title=0&byline=0.
```

As you can see here, there is another difference to YouTube. The arguments start with? and connects the arguments with `&`. Whereas YouTube begins with `&` and also connects the arguments with `&`.

Answer (score 0):

You should [add a filter on oembed provider](https://gist.github.com/benhuson/9f433b7af41a26ef6692) to allow customs parameters:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_fetch_url', 'my_oembed_fetch_url', 10, 3 );

function my_oembed_fetch_url( $provider, $url, $args ) {
    // You can find the list of defaults providers in WP_oEmbed::__construct()
    if ( strpos( $provider, 'vimeo.com' ) !== false) {
        // Check the full list of args here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed
        if ( isset( $args['autoplay'] ) ) {
            $provider = add_query_arg( 'autoplay', absint( $args['autoplay'] ), $provider );
        }
        if ( isset( $args['color'] ) && preg_match( '/^[a-f0-9]{6}$/i', $args['color'] ) ) {
            $provider = add_query_arg( 'color', $args['color'], $provider );
        }
        if ( isset( $args['portrait'] ) ) {
            $provider = add_query_arg( 'portrait', absint( $args['portrait'] ), $provider );
        }
        if ( isset( $args['title'] ) ) {
            $provider = add_query_arg( 'title', absint( $args['title'] ), $provider );
        }
        if ( isset( $args['byline'] ) ) {
            $provider = add_query_arg( 'byline', absint( $args['byline'] ), $provider );
        }
    }

    return $provider;
}
```

then, in your template:

```
<?php wp_oembed_get('http://vimeo.com/44633289', array('color' => '7AB800')); ?>
```

or via a [shortcode](http://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/vimeo/) in post's content:

```
[vimeo 44633289 color=7AB800]
```

and you can do the same for youtube and all others oembed providers (if your `my_oembed_fetch_url` allow it)