# How to set parameters for a Twitter post using wp_oembed_get (remove rounded borders)?

Tags: oembed, twitter

I'm very new to WordPress. I have managed to create a custom field for embedded content (using carbon fields) and oEmbed. It works by simply using the code:

```
echo wp_oembed_get($variable);
```

The `$variable` is retrieved in a loop and contains the URL to a Twitter post. This post is displayed on my index page with (not intended) rounded borders. How do I remove these borders using the parameters `chrome=noborders` [provided by Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/oembed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

> For a single Twitter post, it is not currently possible to remove borders based on [specific parameters](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) for a single Twitter post.

However, I've found two pieces of code that solve the problem, even though I still cannot explain them. The following code (based on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166741/127605)) will enable parameters to be set for a single Twitter post (inside functions.php):

```
function my_oembed_fetch_url( $provider, $url, $args ) {
if ( strpos( $provider, 'twitter.com' ) !== false) {
    // List of args for a single Tweet: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed
    if ( isset( $args['lang'] ) ) {
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'lang', $args['lang'], $provider );
    }
    if ( isset( $args['theme'] ) ) {
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'theme', $args['theme'], $provider );
    }
    if ( isset( $args['align'] ) ) {
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'align', $args['align'], $provider );
    }
    if ( isset( $args['hide_thread'] ) ) {
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'hide_thread', $args['hide_thread'], $provider );
    }
    if ( isset( $args['widget_type'] ) ) {
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'widget_type', $args['widget_type'], $provider );
    }
}
return $provider;
}
add_filter('oembed_fetch_url', 'my_oembed_fetch_url', 10, 3 );
```

Inside template (*for example* index.php), set your desired parameters:

```
echo wp_oembed_get($twitterurl, array('theme'=>'light',widget_type'=>'video'));
```

An alternative code is to set parameters directly inside functions.php, using the following code (based on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/225081/127605)):

```
    add_filter( 'oembed_fetch_url', function( $provider, $url, $args )
    {
    // Target publish.twitter.com provider
    if( 'publish.twitter.com' === parse_url( $provider, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
    $provider = add_query_arg( 'widget_type', 'video', $provider );

    return $provider;
    }, 99, 3 );
```

Inside template, simply use:

```
echo wp_oembed_get($twitterurl);
```